# Best practices for performing a table swap in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, etl

We're in the process of running a handful of hourly scripts on our Redshift cluster which build summary tables for data consumers.  After assembling a staging table, the script then runs a transaction which deletes the existing table and replaces it with the staging table, as such:

```
BEGIN;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.data_facts;
ALTER TABLE public.data_facts_stage RENAME TO data_facts;

COMMIT;
```

The problem with this operation is that long-running analysis queries will place an AccessShareLock on `public.data_facts`, preventing it from being dropped and thrashing our ETL cycle.  I'm thinking a better solution would be one which renames the existing table, as such:

```
ALTER TABLE public.data_facts RENAME TO data_facts_old;
ALTER TABLE public.data_facts_stage RENAME TO data_facts;
DROP TABLE public.data_facts_old;
```

However, this approach presupposes that 1) public.data_facts exists, and 2) public.data_facts_old does not exist.

Do you know if there's a way to conduct this operation safely in SQL, without relying on application logic?  (eg. something like ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS).

Comment: doesn't `AccessShareLock` prevent renaming the table as well?

Comment: Ugh, yes, that appears to be the case.

Comment: do you have rewrite the table completely or the historical part of your table is stable?

Comment: As it stands, the current process involves rewriting the table.

Comment: Another down side on this approach is that views seem to stick to the table as it gets renamed, and then you can't drop it.  (Look at views without schema binding it you're in this space).  Personally, I haven't found anything better than the OP's approach + without schema binding.  Still hoping...

Comment: Hi @RossW. Have you found the solution to this problem? We found it very frustrating, but both "drop table" and "alter table rename" require exclusive lock and cannot be executed while long SELECT is running.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it but looking at [the documentation of `CREATE VIEW`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_VIEW.html) it seems that this can be done with late-binding views.

The main idea would be a view `public.data_facts` that users interact with. Behind the scenes, you can load new data and then swap the view to “point” to the new table.

**Bootstrap**

```
-- load data into public.data_facts_v0
CREATE VIEW public.data_facts AS
SELECT * from public.data_facts_v0 WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING;
```

**Update**

```
-- load data into public.data_facts_v1
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.data_facts AS
SELECT * from public.data_facts_v1 WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING;
DROP TABLE public.data_facts_v0;
```

The `WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING` means the view will be late-binding. “A late-binding view doesn't check the underlying database objects, such as tables and other views, until the view is queried.” This means the update can even introduce a table with renamed columns or a completely new structure.

Notes:

1. It might be a good idea to wrap the swap operations into a [transaction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_BEGIN.html) to make sure we don't drop the previous table if the VIEW swap failed.

Comment: this looks like a clever solution, i hope someone provides feedback.

Comment: Two caveats we found in practice:

1. Some users might use tools that rely on table metadata like the schema. With late binding, these tools might not be able to get the information that they want. They could get it from the underlying table but the whole point is that users don't interact with that table.
2. If users create other tables or views that depend on the view, you won't be able to drop/recreate it during the update *unless* you use `CASCADE` which also deletes all objects that depend on the view. Your customers may or may not be OK with that.

Comment: This is the problem when people are answering without trying or without having experience with the suggested solution.
This solution doesn't work because Redshift also locks view during SELECT. Doesn't matter if the view is late binding or not if you SELECT from it, it cannot be replaced until select is over.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new `load time timestamp encode runlength default getdate()` column to your target table, and make your ETL do this:

```
INSERT INTO public.data_facts
SELECT * FROM public.data_facts_staging;
DELETE FROM public.data_facts
WHERE load_time<(select max(load_time) from public.data_facts);
DROP TABLE public.data_facts_staging;
```

note: `public.data_facts_staging` should have exactly the same structure as `public.data_facts` except that the last column of `public.data_facts` is `load_time`, so that on insert it will be populated with the current timestamp.

The only implication is that it would require extra disk space for a moment between you insert new rows and delete the old rows, and `load_time` has to be always the last column. Also you have to `vaccum` table every time you do this.

Another good thing about this is that if your ETL fails and staging table is empty or there is no staging table you won't lose your data. In the pure SQL scenario of swapping tables with DDL you're not protected from dropping the target table when staging table is missing. In the suggested scenario if no new rows are inserted the delete statement deletes nothing (there are no rows less than max load time), so worst case is just having the old version of data.

p.s. there is a command that instead of `insert ... select ...` just changes the pointer from staging to target table (`alter table ... append from ...`) but it requires the same type of lock as `alter table` I guess, so I don't suggest this

Comment: I'd recommend against this in Redshift.  In a row store this can make sense, but in a column store (like Redshfit) this approach can produce a lot of additional work for the database.  See, e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-time-series-tables.html.